# Send email on click of button with html email

Tags: email, outlook, mailto

I have a question related to **mailTo** feature of HTML that I need in outlook. What I need is initially a system sends me email that has HTML content in it with buttons. On click of one of the buttons, an automatic email should be generated and sent to a recipient. We can do this in 2 step process autofilling the recipient address, subject and body and user can just click send. But I would like to avoid that second step of clicking send again. 

Can I do this using any **script** or **macro** and embed as link/button? Please help.

Comment: There may or may not be a way to do this, but I would be **extremely** unhappy if I clicked something and it sent an email on my behalf. At least make sure it is *very* clear to the user that this is going to happen. I would consider that malicious code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that - spammers would've loved a feature like that...